# How to include the library libasound2 into python-audio-tools

Tags: raspbian

I want to code a CD player application on my Raspberry Pi 2B using python3. So I decided to use the python module "Python Audio Tools" from http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/.

I have already managed to include the necessary library "libcdio" by the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcdio-dev libcdio-paranoia-dev
```

It needs to download 525kB of archives and unzipped 935kB of disk space on the SD card.

So I decided to do something similar on the library "libasound2":

```
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2
```

But now I'll get a message like

```
libasound2 already is the newest version (1.1.3-5+rpi3).
0 updated, 0 new installed, 0 to remove and 0 not updated.
```

(I don't know the exact English text because I use a German localisation).

That means this library should be completely installed on my Raspberry Pi but the installing script (sudo python3 setup.py install) shows this message:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
============================================================================================
Python Audio Tools 3.2alpha2 Setup
============================================================================================
     library present? used for                           download URL
------------ -------- ---------------------------------- -----------------------------------
  libasound2 no       ALSA output                        http://www.alsa-project.org
     libcdio yes      CDDA data extraction
libdvd-audio no       DVD-Audio extraction               http://libdvd-audio.sourceforge.net
   libmpg123 no       MP3/MP2 decoding                   http://www.mpg123.org
    libpulse no       PulseAudio output                  http://www.freedesktop.org
     mp3lame no       MP3 encoding                       http://lame.sourceforge.net
        opus no       Opus encoding                      http://www.opus-codec.org
    opusfile no       Opus decoding                      http://www.opus-codec.org
     twolame no       MP2 encoding                       http://twolame.sourceforge.net
   vorbisenc no       Ogg Vorbis encoding                http://www.xiph.org
  vorbisfile no       Ogg Vorbis decoding                http://xiph.org
     wavpack no       Wavpack decoding, Wavpack encoding http://www.wavpack.com
```

As you can see the library *libcdio* was sucessfully recognized but not the library *libasound2*.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
schlizbaeda

Comment: German speaking users may take a look on https://forum-raspberrypi.de/forum/thread/37359-raspiblaster-cd-player-mit-dem-rpi-oder-wie-binde-ich-libasound2-in-python-audio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer after writing the question:

You have to install the **developer package** of the library to let the Python-Audio-Tools recognize the library.
Instead of

```
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2  # package is already installed
```

which is already installed in the current version of Raspbian Stretch
you have to install

```
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

After that Python-Audio-Tools will recognize this library.

schlizbaeda